# How to display hours worked with hours and minutes

Tags: c#, sql-server

Below is my query and my c# code the problem is i need to display the `Sum` in `hours` and `min` but i am getting this error Invalid usage of `aggregate` function `Sum()` and `Type: String`. How can i solve it ?

Below is my query i have tried so far

```
SELECT ID, name,FromDate,ToDate,CAST(DATEDIFF(Minute,FromDate, ToDate) / 60 AS VARCHAR(5))
+ ' Hrs' + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(Minute, FromDate, ToDate) % 60 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) 
+ ' Min' AS 'Hr' FROM records WHERE convert(date,FromDate,101) 
between convert(date,'" + FromDate + "',101) and 
convert(date,'" + ToDate + "',101) and Name = '" + Name + "'
```

and here is the code

```
                DataTable Dt = adm.GetTeamActivityByNameDates(FromDate.ToString(), ToDate.ToString(), ddlUser.SelectedValue);
                if (Dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    int sum = Convert.ToInt32(Dt.Compute("SUM(Hr)", string.Empty));

                    string Noofact = Dt.Rows.Count.ToString();

                    DataTable dtFinal = new DataTable();
                    dtFinal.Columns.Add("Number");
                    dtFinal.Columns.Add("Sum");

                    DataRow dr = dtFinal.NewRow();
                    dr["Number"] = Noofact;
                    dr["Sum"] = sum;                 
                    dtFinal.Rows.Add(dr);
                    dtFinal.AcceptChanges();
                    if (Dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        grdACT.DataSource = dtFinal;
                        grdACT.DataBind();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }
```

I tried

```
var result = Dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x["Hr"]));
```

also i tried

```
dt.Columns.Add("temp", typeof(int), "Convert(Hr, 'System.Int32')");
var str = dt.Compute("Sum(temp)", "Name='a' and Value is not null");
```

but nothing is working

Comment: I believe the reason you're getting `Invalid usage of aggregate function Sum() and Type: String` is because, in your SQL query, you convert the `Hr` column to a `VARCHAR`.  If you try converting it to a numeric type, does it work?

Comment: can you please show how to do that

Comment: SELECT ID, name,FromDate,ToDate,CAST(DATEDIFF(Minute,FromDate, ToDate) / 60 AS decimal(15,0))
+ ' Hrs' + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(Minute, FromDate, ToDate) % 60 AS  decimal(2,0)), 2) 
+ ' Min' AS 'Hr' FROM records WHERE convert(date,FromDate,101) 
between convert(date,'" + FromDate + "',101) and 
convert(date,'" + ToDate + "',101) and Name = '" + Name + "'

Comment: i am getting Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: The problem is that the column Hr contains data something like `3 Hrs: 10 Min`. This data cannot be converted to double.

Comment: yes it contains the data in that way only

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution similar to what you're trying with LINQ would be simply:

```
float sum = 0;
float outVal = 0;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["Hr"].ToString()))
    {
        if (float.TryParse(dr["Hr"].ToString(), out outVal))
        {
            sum += outVal;
        }
    }
}
```

Then just do whatever you need with the sum.

Comment: it is not working i am getting sum of hours as empty

Comment: @abc Set some break points and step through it. Inspect your DataTable. Does it have the values you expect?

Comment: It is not at all going into this condition

if (Int32.TryParse(dr1["Hr"].ToString(), out outVal))
                            {
                                sum += outVal;
                            }

Comment: @abc Oh, my mistake, try using `Decimal.TryParse` or `Float.TryParse` and changing `outVal` to the same type (`decimal`/`float`). It's probably not a whole number, is it.

Comment: i am getting my required values into dt.rows and dr["Hr"] but it is not going into  if (float.TryParse(dr["Hr"].ToString(), out outVal))
        {
            sum += outVal;
        }

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should not store dates and times as DATETIME - for calculations like that. You should store this value in UTC format (number of seconds since 1950). And then calculate only seconds, so you could get something like 28383. Which is 7 hours(25200 seconds) 53 minutes(3180 secs.) and 3 seconds.

If you need to display human readable datetime IN DATABASE, you should use a view for that which converts number of seconds to human readable format.

Storing date and time as DATETIME has other drawbacks like poor optimization (calculations on integers are far more faster than on DATETIMEs), problems with date format on client computer and so on.

So in application like yours - store all date and time data in seconds. Calculations are simpler and faster. This is not only from my own experience, but I've read a lot about SQL optimization some time ago.

Comment: I'm going to guess this is a school assignment for the question asker, but whether it is or it isn't, changing the entire database schema to use a different type all together and then change the code to fit isn't a viable solution in many cases. Nor does it answer the question of how to display time as both hours and minutes.

Comment: OK, but if it's not a school assignment but regular application, asker will have problems in future with such structure. When I started my worktime application I started it using DATETIMES. But quite fast it has occured that this was a bad idea. So I needed to change it to ints (on working databases :)). It was hard, but the results were awesome.

Comment: "will have problems in the future" maybe; maybe not. Depends entirely on the scale of the application. In my personal experience, I've never once had any issues due to using the `DateTime` format in a DB, but rarely am I dealing with more than 10K records -- and even then, it's often not dependent upon much related to the date fields. They're just there for auditing purposes. In any case, not every business has the resources to just say "OK well we need to take 2+ months to completely re-do our DB and code for some slight optimizations"